# In My SQL i want user to restrict the Drop table and Drop database

Tags: mysql

1. In mysql i want trigger for drop table and alter table, like in sql server we have.

   FOR DROP_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE  triggers

Is there any thing which i can do for it? basically i want the functionality that user should not able to `delete/alter` the table, we can even achieve it by providing restrictive permissions, But we have application in which the customer purchased the sql server so they have root user login and then can do it, so if we add trigger then only i think we can restrict it,

2. Same thing i need to drop database, In SQL server we have 
   `FOR DROP_DATABASE` ,  `DROP_TRIGGER` ,`ALTER_TRIGGER`
   Is there any way to do it in mysql

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is tagged [tag:mysql] when it is almost certainly not about MySQL, for reasons including the fact that the privileged user in MySQL Server is not typically called `sa`.  It appears to be about Microsoft [tag:sql-server].  @DhirajTalele please edit the question and the tags to reflect the correct platform so that the correct people can find your question.

Comment: Thanks Michael, The question is about mysql, I updated my question above, I mean to say root user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the REVOKE command to remove the ALTER and DROP permissions for the user.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27372/blocking-drop-database-command

Comment: But in my case, i don't have control over sa user, because its controller by customer's it department, so sa user will have all the permissions, Is there any other way like triggers or something?

Comment: MySQL does not allow triggers on DDL. The only option is to restrict permissions on all users which can be executed along with your DML scripts.

Comment: Thanks soumyakmurthy,